# How to mask all values with a certain key name in a nested hierarchical object using the DataWeave update operator?

Tags: mask, dataweave, masking

I'm trying to selectively update some values in a nested hierarchical data structure.

I have nested input data such as

```
 var flights = 
{
  "flights": {
    "flight": {
      "airline-name": "american",
      "flight-code": "AA103",
      "plane-type": null,
      "longitude": "33.94250107",
      "price": "+750.00",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "city": "los angeles",
        "altitude": "125",
        "longitude":"33.94250107"
    }
  },
    
  "flight": {
      "available-seats": "+18.00",
      "longitude": "33.94250107",
      "airline-name": "delta",
      "plane-type": "boeing 747",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "longitude": "33.94250107"
      }
    }
 
 }
}
```

I want to mask all the longitudes at all levels with one case statement.

```
flights dw::util::Values::update {
  case dest at .flights.*flight.*destination.longitude  -> "******"
  case ptype at .flights.*flight.*"plane-type" if((ptype ~= null)) -> "*******"
}
```

only matches inside the destination value.

```
{
  "flights": {
    "flight": {
      "airline-name": "american",
      "flight-code": "AA103",
      "plane-type": "*******",
      "longitude": "33.94250107",
      "price": "+750.00",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "city": "los angeles",
        "altitude": "125",
        "longitude": "******"
      }
    },
    "flight": {
      "available-seats": "+18.00",
      "longitude": "33.94250107",
      "airline-name": "delta",
      "plane-type": "boeing 747",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "longitude": "******"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, is there a way to do something like flights..*destination instead of hardcoding the path?

Comment: I think you would have to do .*longitude instead of .longitude. However, easier would be to just use the mask function.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the mask function:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values
var flights = 
{
  "flights": {
    "flight": {
      "airline-name": "american",
      "flight-code": "AA103",
      "plane-type": null,
      "longitude": "33.94250107",
      "price": "+750.00",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "city": "los angeles",
        "altitude": "125",
        "longitude":"33.94250107"
    }
  },
    
  "flight": {
      "available-seats": "+18.00",
      "longitude": "33.94250107",
      "airline-name": "delta",
      "plane-type": "boeing 747",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "longitude": "33.94250107"
      }
    }
 
 }
}
---
(flights mask "longitude" with "****") mask "plane-type" with "****"
```

Output:

```
{
  "flights": {
    "flight": {
      "airline-name": "american",
      "flight-code": "AA103",
      "plane-type": "****",
      "longitude": "****",
      "price": "+750.00",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "city": "los angeles",
        "altitude": "125",
        "longitude": "****"
      }
    },
    "flight": {
      "available-seats": "+18.00",
      "longitude": "****",
      "airline-name": "delta",
      "plane-type": "****",
      "destination": {
        "airport-name": "los angeles international airport",
        "longitude": "****"
      }
    }
  }
}
```